# What is a wiki engine with good client-side javascript/jquery integration?

Tags: javascript, wiki

Can anyone recommend a wiki engine with great support for implementing client-side javascript or jquery?

I'd like to take an existing wiki engine, and it pains me to say it, but add "gmail like" file uploading. I'm sure this can be done with a lot of wiki engines but I'd like to know if any have good support for doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you might like to take a look at existing file upload widgets.  Here are a few for MediaWiki:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UploadWizard

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Add_Media_Wizard

If you do want to roll your own, MediaWiki has reasonable JavaScript support built in:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Tiki Wiki CMS Groupware is a heavy user of jQuery:
http://doc.tiki.org/jQuery

There is also a File/folder management feature:
http://doc.tiki.org/File+Gallery

And there is a database/forms/reports feature:
http://doc.tiki.org/Trackers

And in trackers, attached files are a field type, which has fancy file uploading with modern browsers starting in Tiki8:
http://tikiwiki.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tikiwiki?view=revision&revision=34789

M ;-)